# Yii2 GridView Вывод другого значения

Tags: yii2, gridview

Как в GridView в yii2 вывести в ячейке ,к примеру, если значение 1 - то слово "активно", иначе - "не активно"?

Comment: можно анонимной функцией, я тоже новичок, могу ошибаться :)

Comment: пробовал, пока что не выходит

Comment: `[
  'label' => 'Активность',
  'format' => 'text',
  'value' => return function($model) {
    return $model->is_active ? 'Активен' : 'Не активен';
  }
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'id',
    [
      'label' => 'Активность',
      'format' => 'text',
      'value' => function($model) {
        return $model->is_active ? 'Активен' : 'Не активен';
      }
    ],
    'category.name:text:Имя категории',
    'title',
    'description',
    'date_create',
    'date_update',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']
  ]
]); ?>
```

Примерно вот так

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает, а что нужно дописать что бы работал фильтр по данному полю?

Comment: а какое поле данное?

Comment: а, блин, затупил, не то ответил)) не знаю, можно погуглить

Comment: вот более [крутое решение](http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-sortirovka-i-filtr-gridview-po-svyazannym-i-vychislyaemym-polyam.html) - почитайте, скорее всего найдете то что нужно